Why Hoffman define the subspace spanned by a set?
My mother tongue is not English. If there is anything unclear, please tell me.

I'm curious if anyone knows why Hoffman's book defines "span" in this way. Will this definition be more rigorous? If so, why?
Some linear algebra textbooks define the span this way:
The span of S is the set consisting of all linear combinations of the vectors in S.
How did Hoffman come up with this definition?

The question is unclear. Do you know if the definition you want is equivalent (or not) to the definition of the book?

The related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264018/the-definition-of-span shows that these two definitions are equivalent. So the choice of one definition over the other depends on the author's preferences, e.g. about what is the best pedagogical order in which to develop the material.

Sorry. My mother tongue is not English. I will try to make the question clearer.
I will check about that. Thanks for your link.

This question is similar to: The definition of span.


Those two statement are equivalent. To show that, let $α_1, α_2...α_n$ and the independent vectors $β_1,β_2...β_m$ be in subspace $U$. Let $U_2$ be another subspace that has $α_1, α_2...α_n$ in it, but also has other vectors $γ_1,γ_2...γ_k$ that are independent from alphas. the intersection of those two contain $α_1, α_2...α_n$, and maybe other stuff, as we didn't say that gammas are independent of betas.

Remember that by definition of a vector space if $v \in V$ then $λv \in V $ for $λ$ being in a defined Field $F$ of a Vector space(Usually $F=\mathbb{R}$). Also if  there is another $u \in V$ then $v+u \in V$. Combining those two, we get that if $α_1, α_2...α_n \in U$ then $λ_1α_1+ λ_2α_2 +... +λ_nα_n \in U$. As you can see, this means that if you got any n vectors in a vector space or a subspace, then a linear combination of those vectors also has to be in it.


So we want to make a set of only alphas like we were trying in 1), to guarantee that we will get only alphas in any $V$, we can take the intersection $W$ of every subspace $U_n$ in $V$ containing $α_1, α_2...α_n$, then the only thing that they will have in common will be the mentioned $α_1, α_2...α_n$, by the definition. and As $W$ is still a subspace, we can show by 2) that it contains all of the linear combination of those vectors, therefore W is equal to a span of those alphas.
I think that i dont need to show it other way around, as this was more of a explanation of why is it true. I think the author did it because it's different way of defining it, which gives a reader a broader way of thinking about the span.
I hope that helped, if you need anything more or anyone finds any mistakes, tell me.
